# Sqlite SELECT from relationship of relationship

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am currently working on an android project with a sqlite database. Simplified, I got these three tables:

```
Object: ID, Name

Group: ID, ObjectID, Name

Image: ID, ObjectID, ImageURL
```

An Object has multiple groups and multiple images. Now I want to get all DISTINCT groups and the first image of the first object in the group.

I get all groups like this:

```
SELECT * FROM group_table GROUP BY name;
```

Now I clould get the first object like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM object_table 
    INNER JOIN group_table 
    ON object_table.ID = group_table.ObjectID 
WHERE group_table.Name = "group_sample_name"
```

Last, I could do a third SELECT to get an image for that object. But wouldn't that be kind of too much? I just believe there must be a more cleaner and efficient way to do this.

Comment: Well you could use an ORM if you don't like writing the SQL and populating the objects. Not sure if that's what you mean by `cleaner` or `efficient`

Comment: That is not an option for me. With cleaner i mean by one single statement and not three.

Comment: oh ok. So why not just join image as well. Or do you just want the first image for each group?

Comment: Define "first". Any random object/image?

Comment: First means first inserted, so smallest ID as primary key. I found a solution for one single select with three JOINS like @ConradFrix suggested: `SELECT imageURL FROM image_table LEFT JOIN object_table ON image_table.ID = bjecto_table.ID LEFT JOIN group_table ON object_table.ID = group_table.ObjectID WHERE group_table.Name = "group_sample_name"`. It was more a general design question, like best use or a design pattern that already might exists.